# What is the type of this inner join LINQ query?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join

I annoys me very much when programmers use `var` instead being precise and write the correct type. In Microsoft tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx 
I have found this explanation of inner join(below). What is probably the type of `innerJoinQuery` because it looks like mash up of 2 strings but we don't know what is the result type.

**Quote:**

Join operations create associations between sequences that are not explicitly modeled in the data sources. For example you can perform a join to find all the customers and distributors who have the same location. In LINQ the join clause always works against object collections instead of database tables directly.

```
C#
var innerJoinQuery =
    from cust in customers
    join dist in distributors on cust.City equals dist.City
    select new { CustomerName = cust.Name, DistributorName = dist.Name };
```

In LINQ you do not have to use join as often as you do in SQL because foreign keys in LINQ are represented in the object model as properties that hold a collection of items. For example, a Customer object contains a collection of Order objects. Rather than performing a join, you access the orders by using dot notation:

**EDIT: Let's rephrase this question. What else I can put instead of `var` here?**

Comment: its some form of an `ienumerable<annontype>`

Comment: you have to use `var` in this case.

Comment: Without typeinference (var) there could be no LINQ

Comment: you could put `dynamic` but that defeats the compiler. or you could have it select a new type that you define.

Comment: "It annoys me very much"... I suggest you get over your annoyance and embrace anonymous types. Linq would be a major PITA without them. You're not forgoing any type safety by using them.

Comment: @Zache That's simply not true.  LINQ is in no way dependent on `var`.  In fact, every single C# 3.0 feature added simply made the use of LINQ somewhat more convenient, but it is still *possible* without any of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of this linq query is a *sequence* of objects of an anonymous type with two properties. One of them is called `CustomerName` and the other is called `DistributorName`. Both of them are quite possible of type `string`.

In order you avoid the `var`, you have to declare a class with these two properties, like below:

```
class ClassName
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string DistributorName { get; set; }
}
```

Then you have to change you linq query to the following one:

```
IEnumerable<ClassName> innerJoinQuery =  from cust in customers
                                         join dist in distributors 
                                         on cust.City equals dist.City
                                         select new ClassName 
                                         { 
                                             CustomerName = cust.Name, 
                                             DistributorName = dist.Name 
                                         };
```

However I don't see any benefit in the above approach if you jsut want to get the results of this query and iterate through them or something else. In other words, I think that `var` is used correctly here. I mean it doesn't createa any ambiguities of what you do.

Comment: Using var it will ALWAYS be the correct type. The compiler infers it!

Comment: @Yoda its actually a very smart concept. c++ introduced this as `auto`.

Comment: @Yoda `var` != `dynamic`.

Comment: @Yoda You can use a few things other than `var`, but none of them will allow you to effectively utilize the anonymous type, so for all practical purposes, yes, it's the only option that you have.  If you don't like it, then that's you're choice, you're certainly free to not use it.  You basically won't ever be able to use anonymous types, either.

Comment: @Yoda it looks like java has it in 7, but in IMHO, looks scarier - `MyClass<Integer> myObject = new MyClass<>("");`